# How to create HTML within Azure Function App

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

We have encountered a rather frustrating problem within a Http triggered function app that returns Json data to our front end client application. The problem relates to the usage of the `HtmlContentBuilder` and `TagBuilder` class whilst running .NET Core 3.1.

The API loops through some history records and creates a block of Html content which is included within a Json dataset consumed by the client application.

To construct the Html content we are using `HtmlContentBuilder` to do so.

We did have this building however we were getting the following error: -

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlContentBuilder.WriteTo(System.IO.TextWriter, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder)'
```

I traced this back to a reference to a legacy JwtBearer class that was no longer needed and ultimately removed all of the legacy references which were providing references to classes such as `HtmlContentBuilder` in some obscure fashion.

However, we can no longer even add references to the project to get this compiling, starting afresh Visual Studio makes the following suggestions: -

`HtmlContentBuilder`:`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` v2.2.0

`TagBuilder`:`Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` v3.2.7

The above TagBuilder suggestion results in the following warning: -

```
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

`TagBuilder`:`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures` v2.2.0

The above package installation allows the solution to be built however I am right back where I started with the same error?

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlContentBuilder.WriteTo(System.IO.TextWriter, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder)'
```

Other than resorting to StringBuilder is there an alternative way to build Html content?

Answer (score 0):

OK got to the bottom of it, it was a 3rd party dependency Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage causing the problem version 3.0.1 caused the failure but version 3.0.0 works fine.